# How do i add a currency symbol before a number?

Tags: c#, string, currency

ToString("C") adds $ symbol before a string. But how do I add other currency types such as Yen, Russian Ruble, Indian Rupee, Swiss Frank?

thanks

Comment: If you are actually going to be displaying more than one currency in the same application, it may be well to either forget about symbols and just use codes, or at least use codes together with the symbols; enough symbols are used for more than one currency (the peso/dollar symbol $ in particular) to make it worth being clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can clone the current culture and modify the currency symbol to whatever you want:

```
var culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "!"; // or "¥", etc.

var amount = 1000D;
Console.WriteLine(amount.ToString("C", culture));
```

This outputs "!1,000.00".

Simply specifying a different culture as the other answers suggest will format the number unexpectedly for the user. For example:

```
var amount = 1000D;
Console.WriteLine(amount.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru")));
Console.WriteLine(amount.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("id")));
```

This outputs:

```
1 000,00 р.
Rp1.000
```

Note that the thousands and decimal separators are very different to what I am expecting using the "en-US" culture!

Answer (score 3):

Change culture to [specific country culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488%28v=cs.20%29.aspx) for example :

```
var no = 1000;
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("id-ID");
Console.WriteLine(no.ToString("C", culture));
```

will print in Indonesian's Rupiah symbol :

```
Rp1.0000
```

Comment: Just specifying the CultureInfo for the relevant culture isn't going to work, as you'll get the formatting for the entire number. e.g. if my culture is en-US, I don't want '.' as the thousands separator like in your example.

Answer (score 3):

`ToString` has an overload that accepts an [`IFormatProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine(amount.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ja-JP")));
```

Sample output: `¥5`

More here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#CFormatString

Answer (score 3):

To do this you would have to specify the locale of the currency you wish to display. Below is an example of what I believe you are looking for.

```
object.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ja-JP"))
```

That sample should return the value of object with a Japanese Yen symbol before it. For using different currencies you should refer to:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.createspecificculture(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.createspecificculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
it contains a list of available options.

For more info on formatting strings look here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#CFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#CFormatString)